# Why use Г in for example Горизонт and not for example Х?

Tags: этимология, правописание, буквы, алфавит

I am just a happy beginner in Russian language, but to my ears Х sounds closer to H than Г.

Does anyone know why words like Horizon (Горизонт) choose Г instead?

Is there some historic explanation of when the words came into the language or how it evolved?

Comment: Already answered here: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/222/2104

Comment: your question based on assumption that `x` is sort of close in pronunciation to `h` compared to `г` - which is actually debatable.